# Python + BeautifulSoup: Finding a HTML tag where an attribute contains a matched pattern of text?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm new to both Python and BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to figure out how to match only the tags that are `<div>` elements that contain a certain matched pattern of text belonging to an attribute. For example, all cases where the `'id' : 'testid'`, or everywhere the `'class' : 'title'`.

This is what I have so far:

```
def cleanup(filename):
    fh = open(filename, "r")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(fh, 'html.parser')

    for div_tag in soup.find('div', {'class':'title'}):
        h2_tag = soup.h2_tag("h2")
        div_tag.div.replace_with(h2_tag)
        del div_tag['class']

    f = open("/tmp/filename.modified", "w")
    f.write(soup.prettify(formatter="html5"))
    f.close()
```

Once I can match all those particular elements, at that point I can figure out how to manipulate the attributes (delete the class, rename the tag itself from `<div>` to `<h1>`, etc). So I'm aware that actual part of the cleanup probably doesn't work with how it is currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this works sufficiently, but let me know if there's a "better" or "more standard" way to do it.

```
for tag in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'title'}):
    del tag['class']
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find(tagName, attributes)` return single element

`.find_all(tagName, attributes)` return multiple element (list)

more you can find it in the [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

to replace you need to create element `.new_tag(tagName)` and to delete attribute `del element.attrs[attributeName]` see below for example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = '''
<div id="title" class="testTitle">
  heading h1
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print 'html before'
print soup

div = soup.find('div', id="title")

#delete class attribute
del div.attrs['class']

print 'html after remove attibute'
print soup

# to replace, create h1 element
h1 = soup.new_tag("h1")
# set text from previous element
h1.string = div.text
# uncomment to set ID
# h1['id'] = div['id']
div.replace_with(h1)

print 'html after replace'
print soup
```